# Unity: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Mesh' to 'UnityEngine.Mesh[]'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Getting an error when trying to use a string with meshes in unity:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Mesh' to 'UnityEngine.Mesh[]'

**[Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHnzI.png)**

EC: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Mesh' to 'UnityEngine.Mesh[]'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class HatSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MeshFilter modelYouWantToChange;
    [SerializeField] private Mesh[] modelYouWantToUse;

    private int currentModel;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            modelYouWantToChange.mesh = modelYouWantToUse[currentModel];
            currentModel++;

            if (currentModel >= modelYouWantToUse.Length)
            {
                currentModel = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void ChangeMeshButton()
    {
        modelYouWantToChange.mesh = modelYouWantToUse[currentModel];
        currentModel++;

         if (currentModel >= modelYouWantToUse.Length)
         {
             currentModel = 0;
         }
    }

    public void ChangeMeshButtonBack()
    {
        modelYouWantToChange.mesh = modelYouWantToUse[currentModel];
        currentModel--;

        if (currentModel >= modelYouWantToUse.Length)
        {
            currentModel = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to create a skin changer for a game :

[Seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXCTS.png)

Comment: Exactly what it says. You are trying to convert a mesh to an array of meshes.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b how would I fix this then

Comment: @RufusL - that was a mistake - I have removed this, but the problem still occurs

Comment: Which line(s) cause this because you use modelYouWantToChange.mesh a couple of times and you cant do an array of something .mesh. You need to pick an element.

Comment: In the `ChangeMeshButtonsBack` method, since we're decrementing `currentModel`, we should be checking if it's less than `0`, not greater than `Length`. For example: `if (currentModel < 0) currentModel = modelYouWantToUse.Length - 1;`

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to change the mesh of the object everytime I press a UI button and need an array to have multiple items @BugFinder

Comment: In the `Update` method, instead of repeating the same code as in the `ChangeMeshButton` method, you should just call that method directly. This way if you ever need to change that code, it only has to be done in one place. For example: `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) ChangeMeshButton();`

Comment: Which line is thowing the exception?

Comment: the models mesh is not switching. The mesh switching was working with a single item but not for an array of items - there is no error anymore using: modelYouWantToUse = new Mesh[] {modelYouWantToChange.mesh};

Comment: Why did you make that change? Why would you set the array to contain only a single item? In the original code, which line was throwing the exception?

Comment: @RufusL the Mesh[] on line 9

Comment: Line 9 wont be causing the error. You have an array. As i pointed out just like you cant take int[] and perform 1 operation on the name of the array. You cant take your array and just so .mesh and set it to something. You need to pick an element of the array. Its not clear even in your code if you initialised the array but assuming you did in the inspector. I get you want to change the mesh i just dont see clearly in your code how you think you are doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which line is causing the exception, it's not clear how the `modelYouWantToUse` array is being populated, and I don't know Unity at all, but here's how I would do it:

```
public class HatSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MeshFilter modelToChange;
    [SerializeField] private Mesh[] meshItems;

    private int currentMeshIndex = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) ChangeMesh();
    }

    public void ChangeMesh()
    {
        // Update the mesh
        modelToChange.mesh = meshItems[currentMeshIndex];

        // Increment our index
        currentMeshIndex++;

        // Validate index is in range
        if (currentMeshIndex >= meshItems.Length) currentMeshIndex = 0;
    }

    public void ChangeMeshBack()
    {
        // Update the mesh
        modelToChange.mesh = meshItems[currentMeshIndex];

        // Decrement our index
        currentMeshIndex--;

        // Validate index is in range
        if (currentMeshIndex < 0) currentMeshIndex = meshItems.Length - 1;
    }
}
```